# Call method when object deserialized

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an object that has some setters doing something but it requires this object must be fully deserialized. I would like to know if it can call method (to turn a flag on) when it deserialized.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the [ISupportInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx) method. See our documentation at  http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/mapping/#isupportinitialize